# Why yahoo finance API returns quotes with fractions smaller than cents?

Tags: yahoo-finance

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/MSFT?period1=1623070800&period2=1623638698&interval=1d&includePrePost=False&events=div%2Csplits

I see yahoo finance returns quotes with fractions smaller than cents. I'd expect real quotes to be in cents. Could anybody let me know what a fraction of a cent means?

```
indicators": {
"quote": [
{
"close": [
253.80999755859375,
252.57000732421875,
253.58999633789062,
257.239990234375,
257.8900146484375
],
"open": [
249.97999572753906,
255.16000366210938,
253.80999755859375,
254.2899932861328,
257.989990234375
],
"low": [
249.80999755859375,
252.50999450683594,
253.2100067138672,
253.6699981689453,
256.6099853515625
],
"high": [
254.08999633789062,
256.010009765625,
255.52999877929688,
257.4599914550781,
258.489990234375
],
"volume": [
23079200,
22455000,
17937600,
24563600,
18995100
]
}
],
"adjclose": [
{
"adjclose": [
253.80999755859375,
252.57000732421875,
253.58999633789062,
257.239990234375,
257.8900146484375
]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly when stored as binary fractions.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html